# Exclude slides from PowerPoint handout

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I'm creating lecture presentations in PowerPoint (2010) and would like to be able to exclude some of the slides from the lecture handouts. I would have thought there'd be a 'properties' tab for each slide, and I'd be able to select 'exclude from handout'. Apparently not.

I *could* just create a second PowerPoint with some of the slides deleted, but this becomes laborious if I decide to make last-minute changes to one of the slides, as I would then need to produce a new handout file. Furthermore, I would like my students to be able to print their own handouts from the PPT file if possible, so specifying a reduced page range when printing is impractical.

I know this is possible it TeX, but I am wedded to Microsoft as this is what the entire department uses.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just for clarification. You are not looking for this option: `Powerpoint » Slides » Set up Slide Show » Show Slides » From XX to YY`, right?

Comment: No, my PowerPoint presentation will include *all* the slides; I just intend on excluding some of the slides from the handouts.

Answer (score 2):

You can designate some slides as hidden. When a presentation includes hidden slides, there's an option to print or not print hidden slides in the print dialog box.

If you include all of your slides in a Custom Show and then in the Set Up Slide Show dialog, tell PPT to play the custom show rather than starting with slide 1, all of the slides, hidden ones included, will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks @Steve; this is close to what I'm looking for, but by hiding the slides, they won't show when I actually deliver the lecture, and the students would also have to manually select the 'no-print' option when creating their handouts...

Comment: "by hiding the slides, they won't show when I actually deliver the lecture" ... no, not so.  If you link to a custom show, the slides will appear, hidden or not.  Same should be true of doing it as I described.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I completely glazed over the words 'Custom Show'. I didn't realise this was an option within PowerPoint (rather, I thought you were referring to a whole other PPT file). Looks like this is what I'm looking for. However, the 'hidden' slides remain hidden, even if I play the Custom Show. Do you know any way to get around this?

Comment: You need to either tell PPT to play the custom show when you start the slide show (Slide Show | Set Up Show | Choose Custom Show under "Show slides") or put a link to the custom show on a visible slide.

Comment: Thanks, but even if I play the custom show, the hidden slides are still hidden

Comment: If your custom show begins with a non-hidden slide, then PPT won't show the rest of the hidden slides.  If the first slide in the custom show is hidden, then PPT will play it and the remainder of the hidden slides.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case :/

Maybe I need to upgrade my version of PowerPoint. I'm on 2010 at the moment.

Comment: Works here.  In 2010.  Don't know what to say ...

Comment: It also fails for me in PowerPoint 2010. For those of you that it is working for, try "Set up slide show" to select your custom show as the default.

Comment: @sturgman I just tested this with 2016. It does not work when starting the presentation the usual way (via `F5` or the normal start), but when you open the first slide and use start from current slide (or `SHIFT+F5`), it _does_ work [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if "if and only if") the very first slide is hidden. So I had to duplicate my first slide (since that is supposed to also show up in the exported PDF or printout), but _exclude_ it from the custom show...

Comment: @CaptainProg Did you also try starting at a hidden slide _and_ use the "start from here" / `SHIFT+F5` function?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler This only works if my hidden slide is at the beginning of the slideshow, and there is only one of them...

Comment: @CaptainProg Only one hidden slide? For me it worked with more than one as well, but as mentioned I had to duplicate the first slide and exclude that from the custom slideshow

Comment: Hm, this is highly unreliable - yesterday it seemed to work just fine, now it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Make it the other way around.
Create a new Custom SlideShow called NoAnimation. Add all slides except those used to animate.
On the Print Screen select the Custom SlideShow you just created, which does NOT have the slides you want.

Comment: Also a nice suggestion, too bad Adobe's PDF export does not provide that option...